# Unable to delete this post

Tags: feature-request, editing, close-reasons, vote-to-close, down-votes

I have been wanting to delete [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343783/defining-a-measure-of-uniformity-that-finds-the-most-uniform-structure-for-the) for quite sometime. Unfortunately a user already answered and my reputation is so low that I can’t accept or delete it.

Note my original question is nothing like my recent one. I completely transformed it since the shift in my “research” has completely changed; however, it has changed so drastically that the comments to my post, along with the answer, do not correlate.

Is it possible to get the mods to delete my post?

Comment: I have flagged the question for moderator attention

Comment: Just to clarify: You're asking to the delete *the question*, right? (You don't mean deleting *the answer* and leaving the question.)

Comment: The mentioned post is deleted now.

Comment: "my reputation is so low that I can’t accept or delete it." Does a user really need to have some number of points in order to accept an answer to his/her own question?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I meant delete the question

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your right. I could just accept the answer but I didn’t think it was correct. And my post is so contaminated I would rather have it deleted.

Comment: Just a side remark -- deleting the question apparently caused a 100-points-bounty on the question from 2019 to be refunded.

Comment: @StefanKohl There are several posts on [meta.se] related to this, such as [When a question that had bounties is deleted, are they automatically refunded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145329) and [other questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/145329). There is also the section "What happens if a question where I awarded a bounty later gets deleted or migrated?" in the FAQ post [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)